# Why use an antistatic solvent dispenser bottle?

Tags: esd, antistatic

What reasons are there to have an antistatic solvent dispenser bottle (for cleaning your PCBs after soldering) as opposed to a solvent dispenser bottle that is not antistatic rated? I am specifically asking about the kind of bottles that have a stainless steel dispenser, such as the R&R Lotion bottles seen here: http://rrlotion.com/product/anti-splash-pump-solvent-dispensers-esd/

I have found several standards that suggest keeping anything that is not ESD safe at least 12 inches away from your ESD sensitive items, which is a good rule, but are there any other reasons why a dispenser bottle should be antistatic? Is there a reason why I shouldn’t purchase a solvent dispenser bottle that is not ESD safe and keep it further than 12 inches away from my ESD sensitive things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking ESD protection is a bigger concern in larger scale manufacturing and production setting than it is for the homebrewer or r&d engineer.

The can specifically can pick electrostatic charge from *you* as you are moving around the house/shop and can store that charge as a weak capacitor at high potential. Your concerns about 12" is a general recommendation about keeping potential ESD sources away from sensitive electronics.

It is also quite likely that the manufacturer of the "non-ESD safe" version of the product container simply never bothered to go through ESD-safety verification or simply wishes to create a more expensive product for customers that require that validation.

If you are working at home or in a small lab it is very likely that you will have no problems using either product and ESD may not even register as a concern.  At the very least you could test the product in house quickly and be confident that its ok to you. On the other side of the coing in a manufacturing setting a technician may be running around to multiple stations and working with a much higher volume of devices that purchasing verified ESD safe products becomes a valid business concern.

To specifically answer your question, if ESD is a concern to you, you will be safer as a general rule keeping non-esd rated items 12" away from the device or have a system to bleed charge. Keeping a solvent can on a grounded ESD pad will probably be enough verification for me personally . After all, a person is the biggest ESD danger in the room and you are comfortable handling the device after ESD precautions are taken.

Answer (score 2):

Selecting the wrong plastic when making a solvent bottle could cause electrostatic charge to be generated by rubbing something over it. It being an insulator would allow it to retain that charge on the surface.  Having a conductive liquid inside could theoretically make a solvent bottle into a [Leyden jar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leyden_jar) and a stream of conducting solvent could theoretically allow a charge imbalance to be discharged when impinging on a device under test.

I think the danger from the pump bottles you reference is remote as the amount of charge transferred by a wet wipe or cleaning brush dipped in the cup will be small and drained to your hand on the way to the DUT, a siphon type bottle might have a bit more risk.

A conducting plastic would be all that is required to eliminate the static issues in practice, you may find that black plastic (with carbon black filler) will serve the purpose.

If I **had** to make a siphon bottle static proof then I would drill a hole in the bottom, fit a sealed end stainless steel expanding/POP rivet, with washers and rubber seal, through the hole to make electrical contact to the solvent. Then stick a conductive foam pad or conductive tape on the bottom and up the sides in contact with the rivet head to keep everything at a common potential.

With the pump top dispenser you could use metal containers if you can find a mating thread.  Check out camping stores or other cosmetic products.  Alternately if you place a conductive tape from top to bottom and up the other side trapped by the metal threads you would also be safe when it is on the antistatic work surface as the opening is 'grounded' and any remotely possible charge will remain inside.